# Which Facebook class is used to retrieve feeds in iPhone ios 6

Tags: iphone

I'm working on facebok integration in my Native IOS App ios 6,

I can able to retrieve the Facebook friends list using FBFriendPickerViewController class,
 and i can retrieve near by places using FBPlacePickerViewController  class, now i want retrieve the facebook feeds which class i should use .

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the API

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID&viewer=YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID&key= YOUR_INTERNAL_KEY&format=rss20

And Here is the [link](http://www.methodshop.com/2010/02/facebook-rss-feed.shtml) from which i found above API. Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SLRequest class and point it to whichever Graph API endpoint that you want information from.

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID", ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                         nil];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        ACAccount *account = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType] lastObject];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{};
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/SOME_GRAPH_ENDPOINT"];
        SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                          URL:url
                                                   parameters:parameters];
        request.account = account;
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            NSError *jsonerror;
            NSDictionary *myData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonerror];
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@, %@",error,[error description]);
    }
}];
```